# :config of use-package is not working for multiple cursors

Tags: use-package, config, multiple-cursors

I have noticed a weird behaviour with `use-package` for `multiple-cursors` when trying to customize [insertion of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29838244/how-to-insert-a-number-sequence-in-emacs-with-multiple-cursors).

I am able to insert numbers on multiple cursors using `C-c n` using this code

```lisp
;; Multiple Cursors
(use-package multiple-cursors
  :ensure t
  :bind(("C-S-c C-S-c" . mc/edit-lines)
        ("C-»" . mc/mark-next-like-this)
        ("C-«" . mc/mark-previous-like-this)
        ("C-c C-«" . mc/mark-all-like-this))
  )   
(setq mc/insert-numbers-default 1)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c n") 'mc/insert-numbers)
```

but this alternative declaration of multiple-cursors does not produce the same effect, i.e., when pressing `C-c n` there is no keybinding associated and no numbers are inserted on the cursors.

```lisp
;; Multiple Cursors
(use-package multiple-cursors
  :ensure t
  :bind(("C-S-c C-S-c" . mc/edit-lines)
        ("C-»" . mc/mark-next-like-this)
        ("C-«" . mc/mark-previous-like-this)
        ("C-c C-«" . mc/mark-all-like-this))
  :config
  (setq mc/insert-numbers-default 1)
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-c n") 'mc/insert-numbers)
  )
```

This is strange since the whole point of `:config` is to run code after the package is loaded, which is the intended purpose here. It works fine for other packages as far as I can tell. Any thoughts?

Comment: You said that there is a “weird behaviour” but not what was weird. Did you get an error message or something?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. What is weird is that the :config option does not seem to work in this particular case, although when the setq and keybinding commands are written after the use-package construct they work fine. Incidentally, these commands allow to insert sequence of numbers along the multiple cursors

Comment: “does not seem to work” is still a bit indefinite. Have you used `C-h v` to inspect the value of the `mc/insert-numbers-default` variable, for example? Note that packages are lazily loaded, so “after the package is loaded” could easily be after you first call a function defined in the package.

Comment: I've updated the question to try to shed some extra light. Ic. Is there any workaround/alternative way to invoke the package? Also, are you able to reproduce the same behaviour? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, I think the problem is that loading `multiple cursors` is deferred, and so your `:config` code doesn't get loaded prior to the first time you use a `mc` command. The `:bind` argument exists to deal with this. Try the following:

```lisp
(use-package multiple-cursors
  :ensure t
  :bind(("C-S-c C-S-c" . mc/edit-lines)
        ("C-»" . mc/mark-next-like-this)
        ("C-«" . mc/mark-previous-like-this)
        ("C-c C-«" . mc/mark-all-like-this)
        ("C-c n" . mc/insert-numbers))
  :config
  (setq mc/insert-numbers-default 1)
  )
```

Comment: Thanks. With your solution I am indeed able to insert numbers. However, the `setq` command, which sets the default number at which the count starts from, is set to 0 (not 1).

Comment: * I meant to say the `mc/insert-numbers-default` variable - not the setq command

Comment: @Ajned switch `:config` to `:init` to force the setq command to be called earlier

Comment: Thanks @Tyler. It works like a charm but I cannot understand why. Being `mc/insert-numbers-default` a variable from multiple-cursors why do I need to set it before the package is loaded? O_O Thank you in advance for any explanation/pointers to documentation